# Trying to find a sci-fi novel: only remember the dirty bits

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I read this book a very long time ago (perhaps about 20 years back), hence limited recall.

It's sci-fi, the part I remember has a character who is piloting some kind of spaceship/fighter and part of the technical lore involves making use of implants to push past normal human limits (including for sexual recreation). I remember something specific about one of the characters using an implant to be ready for sex immediately rather than waiting for a few minutes.

This story is NOT The Gap Into series by Stephen Donaldson. Unfortunately cannot remember much else, it's one of those I'll know it when I see it things.

edit: Thanks everyone who commented. I've updated the question with further information in response above, and will go through the FAQ prompts here with responses to commentators below:

Media: I think it's a fairly chunky novel (at least an inch thick paperback), I can't recall if it's part of a series (although this is likely), if so, it's likely the first book only I read.

Year of publication: Not sure, would be published before or during late 90's.

Major themes: All I can recall is space stations, piloting space ships, space in general, some military contexts, but non-military also.  Detailed technical world-building.

Language: English/American English

Target audience: Adult sci-fi, definitely not written for teens

NOT: I don't think it's Asimov, Clarke, Dick, Herbert, Orwell, Verne.  All others are possible.

To commenters:

The Culture novels and Delaney/Asaro's books seem like strong contenders, I am going to go skim them to see what seems familiar.  Regarding the type of sexual content, I don't recall anything too crazy (i.e. no threesomes, alien sex), but it may well have featured light to medium BDSM (i.e. orgasm denial, enhanced sensation).

I don't recall pirates in the story, for that matter also no zombies.  Perhaps aliens, I don't recall.  I am definitely going to read all the works mentioned below though (particularly Hamilton's books, reow).

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Perhaps a look at [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) article will help jog your memory for more details. Also, a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) is recommended for new users.

Comment: This seems incredibly broad and matches any number of books. You need to be much more specific.

Comment: The Culture novels from Ian Banks describe modifications like these, including sexual enhancements.

Comment: As described, this could match **Babel-17** by Samuel R. Delaney or **Primary Inversion** by Catherine Asaro, and that's just off the top of my head.  Or it could match a porn story.  How do they push pass the limits?  What's open?  Just hetero sex?  Same sex sex?  Group?  Kinky?  Pain?  What's a very long time to you?  Ten years?  Twenty?  Forty?  Eighty?  Why do you say it's hard sci-fi if you don't remember it?  Hard is not a sex reference in that tag name.  Note that implants aren't normally hard sci-fi, as they tend to be handwavey.

Comment: It could also be Peter Hamilton's "Night's Dawn" trilogy. As someone once described it: "The over-sexed space pirates versus the living dead."  The space captain has whole sections of his ship devoted to sexual recreation AND implants.

Comment: @Politank-Z (and others) thanks for your interest and steering toward the article, I tried to make use of it in my revised question.  Meanwhile I'll be reviewing the books mentioned thus far, thanks again for the suggestions!

Comment: I think I know this one. Does it have people who are surgically altered for jobs? One of which is a spacer with only a head and two arms so they can get into small areas on spaceships in microgravity?